# Start minikube dashboard in remote computer through ssh

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, minikube

I installed minikube in a remote computer. The service is up and the configuration looks ok:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.49.2:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.49.2:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

I am connected to this computer through SSH and am able to launch all graphic applications. Sanity check, confirming X11 forwarding is allowed:

```
$ grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
X11Forwarding yes
```

But when I try to start the dashboard I get an X11 error:

```
$ minikube dashboard
* Verifying dashboard health ...
* Launching proxy ...
* Verifying proxy health ...
* Opening http://127.0.0.1:39571/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ in your default browser...
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
[61559:61559:1119/114641.640444:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1434)] Unable to open X display.
```

What could be the cause?

**Update**: replying to [larks below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910125/start-minikube-dashboard-in-remote-computer-through-ssh?noredirect=1#comment114761931_64910125), the `ForwardX11Trusted` parameter is set to `yes` on the SSH client:

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep ForwardX11Trusted
   ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Comment: What if you set `ForwardX11Trusted` in your ssh *client* configuration?

Comment: @larks `ForwardX11Trusted` **is** set in the client. I am updating the question.

Comment: There can be plenty of reasons for that. You may need to `export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority`. Also make sure `~/.Xauthority` is owned by you. Run `ls -l ~/.Xauthority` to verify it. You may need to fix permissions on that file with  `chown user:group ~/.Xauthority` and `chmod 0600 ~/.Xauthority`.

Comment: @mario It started working once I set up the `XAUTHORITY` variable. Could you please add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Luís de Sousa, sure, just added my answer. I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be plenty of reasons for that. You may just need to:

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

Also make sure `~/.Xauthority` is owned by you.

In order to verify it, run:

```
ls -l ~/.Xauthority
```

And then, depending on the result, you may need to fix ownership and permissions on that file with:

```
chown user:group ~/.Xauthority
```

and

```
chmod 0600 ~/.Xauthority
```